# webpack-internal in console opens in new browser tab with empty page [Next.js]

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have been having trouble working with webpack-internal in Next.js app.

Whenever there are errors and console says:

```
at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:87:23)
```

and whenever I click on it, to view the file in the source tab, it opens in a new Chrome browser tab with an empty page instead of linking it to the source tab of dev tools.

Is there any special configuration required to work with Webpack in next.js or any configuration to set in Chrome browser to open the source tab of Webpack instead of loading it in a new browser?

I can go to the source tab and see all generated source maps manually, but it is just not available on click. On click, these links open in browser's new tab

Comment: Are you using `sourcemap` with webpack?

Comment: next.js comes with it by default and I can go to source tab and see all generated source map manually, but it is just not available on click. On click, these links open in browser new tab

Comment: I have the exact same issue.